Firebase phone authentication for react native applications
I am trying to create a project that I want to run on and iOS and an Android device.
I am planning to use react native and for the backend I was planning to use Java Springboot but the firebase says to add dependencies for phone number authentication to app level build.gradle and project level build.gradle. But, I created the backend using springinitializr.io (that has a single build.gradle).
Question: Should I add the extra build.gradle or should I just import the libraries and use the Firebase functions? what difference does it make?
I tried adding all the dependencies mentioned on the Firebase configurations in the single build.gradle file that I have but that does not seem to work.

Also, I was thinking should I manage the phone number authentication over at the front end or the backend of the application? Also, is firebase the best service for login/sign up in an application using phone numbers or email ids?
